# how to get a word under cursor in windows application

Tags: c#, windows, windows-rt

I saw many questions that try to get the word under a cursor on Windows but that doesn't completely answer my question.

I want to try and get the word under the cursor for a Windows Store Application. I am developing an application for Microsoft Surface. The app page has a bunch of text and if a user's mouse hovers over the word I would like to display some feedback as well as the word they hovered on. I am developing using C#.

I would like to do something like in this example -->

```
<p><span>Some</span> <span>long</span> <span>text</span></p>

<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('p span').bind('mouseenter', function () {
    alert($(this).html() + " is what you're currently hovering over!");
  });
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5bT4B/

but for Windows Store Application.

Comment: Are you interested in C# or jQuery solution (as shown in your example)? Please specify. Rgds, Alex